# Precision of the kinect depth camera

Tags: kinect, depth

How precise is the depth camera in the kinect?

- range?
- resolution?
- noise?

Especially I'd like to know:

- Are there any official specs about it from Microsoft?
- Are there any scientific papers on the subject?
- Investigations from TechBlogs?
- Personal experiments that are easy to reproduce?

I'm collecting data for about a day now, but most of the writers don't name their sources and the values seem quite to differ...

Comment: OP should clarify what data they want. Different FOV angles below are due to a) the different sensors and data in a Kinect (RGB v. Depth) and b) pre- or post-aligned, etc.

Comment: be careful to check everything physically with your kinect. there are more versions out there with very different depth parameters for instance mine use 16 bit raw data values not 11/12/13 bit !!! which is nowhere mentioned (raw data format is different) (mine model is 1414 for XBOX360+PC reduction...really old) it have min depth range ~0.95m !!!. on newer models you can get as close as ~0.4m. Driver for newer models seems to work correctly with older models. also if you want to use of accelerometers you should know that access is not fast ~10ms and their precision is also poor ~1%

Comment: after some more precise measurements of my kinect i determine that it has depth resolution ~0.121 mm and the raw data is linear on range up to 2.0 m after that i have not checked.

Comment: the raw data has 0.121 mm per value but the sensor use around 32x that per step so the real depth resolution is around 3.872 mm

Answer (score 29, accepted):

- Range: ~ 50 cm to 5 m. Can get closer (~ 40 cm) in parts, but can't have the full view be < 50 cm.
- Horizontal Resolution: 640 x 480 and 45 degrees vertical FOV and 58 degrees horizontal FOV. Simple geometry shows is about ~ 0.75 mm per pixel x by y at 50 cm, and ~ 3 mm per pixel x by y at 2 m.
- Depth resolution: ~ 1.5 mm at 50 cm. About 5 cm at 5 m.
- Noise: About +-1 DN at all depths, but DN to depth is non-linear. This means +-1 mm close, and +- 5 cm far.

There are official specs from the sensor developer, not from Microsoft. No scientific papers that I know of yet. Plenty of investigations and experiments (see Google). The [OpenKinect](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/openkinect) has a lot more discussion on these things than this site for now.

Comment: mankoff: Do you have a reference for those specs or are those based on your own experiments?

Comment: My own experiments for everything but FOV which comes from sensor specs

Answer (score 12):

The Kinect for Windows SDK provide some constants which I've been using and seem to be consistent. For **range** and **resolution**, these values are:

In default mode:

- Minimum range: 80 cm
- Maximum range: 400 cm

In near mode:

- Minimum range: 40 cm
- Maximum range: 300 cm

For the color camera, you may have either of the following resolutions:

- 80x60
- 320x240
- 640x480
- 1280x960

For the depth camera, you may have either of the following resolutions:

- 80x60
- 320x240
- 640x480

Confronting the information from [Avada Kedavra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/280104/avada-kedavra) (and from most sources, by the way), the values for the **field of view** given by the API are the following:

For the color camera:

- Horizontal FOV: 62,0°
- Vertical FOV: 48,6°

For the depth camera:

- Horizontal FOV: 58,5°
- Vertical FOV: 45,6°

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh855368

Answer (score 7):

The real question here was about resolution and precision. I care to chip in here as i find the resolution and precision to be not as good as stated. The maximum output of the depth resolution is indeed 640x480, however, this is not the effective resolution, and this is not exactly how precise it is.

The method in which the kinect works is based on structured light projection. A pattern of light is emitted and cast on the surface, which a camera sees and then triangulates each ray from the origin, bounced off the object, to the camera.

**The thing is that this pattern consists out of only 34.749 bright spots that can be triangulated** (http://azttm.wordpress.com/2011/04/03/kinect-pattern-uncovered/). If we relate this to a resolution of  640x480=307.200 data points, we notice a great difference. Ask yourself if the amount of data 10 times the amount of source-data-points can be seen as valid, and sampled efficiently. I doubt it. If you were to ask me what the effective resolution of the kinect is, i would guess it is around **240x180** of honest and pretty good data.

Comment: note that the new Kinect doesn't use structured light (PrimeSense), but Time of Flight mechanism (Canesta)

Answer (score 5):

According to [Kinect tech spec finally revealed](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/digitalfoundry-kinect-spec-blog-entry) the specs for the depth field are (these match is also confirmed in the official programming guide as posted by Mannimarco):

```
* Horizontal field of view: 57 degrees
* Vertical field of view: 43 degrees
* Physical tilt range: ± 27 degrees
* Depth sensor range: 1.2m - 3.5m
* Resolution depth stream: 320x240 pixels
* Resolution color stream: 640x480 pixels
```

But from my own experience the depth sensor range is more like `0.8m-4.0m`, at least I get good reading in this range. This range matches the Primesense data sheet posted by mankoff in the comments below.

*It is also important to remember that the depth resolution is much higher close to the sensor than further away.* At 3-4 meter the resolution is not nearly as good as at 1.5m. This becomes important if you, for example, want to calculate the normals of the surface. The result will be better closer to the sensor than further away.

Its not to hard to test the range yourself. The Official SDK (currently beta) will give you a a zero (0) depth when you are out of range. So, you could test this with a simple ruler, and test at what distance you get/dont get any reading larger than zero. I do not know how the OpenKinect SDK handles out-of-range readings.

A comment about noise: I would say that there is quite a bit of noise in the depth stream which makes it harder to work with. For example if you calculate the surface normals you can expect them to be a bit "jumpy" which of course will have a negative impact on fake lighting etc. Furthermore you have a parallax issue in the depth stream due to the distance between the IR transmitter and the receiver. This can also be hard to work with as it leave a large "shadow" in the depth data. [This youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/user/kotsoft#p/u/2/bnsyDOb77eI) demonstrates the problem and discuss a way to resolve the issue using shaders. Its a video worth watching.

Comment: There **are** official specs. See data sheets here: http://openkinect.org/wiki/Hardware_info

Comment: @mankoff: Thanks for sharing this. Its an interesting link. The hardware datasheets referenced are, however, *very* low-level and I can't find anything on the page you link to that answers the OP's (and my own) questions regarding the depth sensor range, depth resolution etc. And also, using openkinect.org as source of official specs? They may be kinect Gods, but they are not official. :)

Comment: Sorry wrong link. Try this PDF http://db.tt/N1SxqFvp I'm not linking to OpenKinect as official, just to links on their pages.

Answer (score 2):

I think it might be worth mentioning the paper of Khoshelham and Elbernik who did propose a theoretical random error model of the kinects depth sensor in Feb '12. It is called "Accuracy and Resolution of Kinect Depth Data for Indoor Mapping Applications".
The paper can be found [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3304120/).

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for something published by Microsoft, check out page 11 of the [Kinect Programming Guide](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/kinectsdk/docs/ProgrammingGuide_KinectSDK.pdf). It says pretty much the same thing everyone here has already mentioned.

- Range: 1.2 to 3.5 meters
- Viewing angle: 43° vertical by 57° horizontal
- Mechanized tilt range: ±28°
- Frame rate: 30 frames per second
- Resolution, depth stream: 320 x 240 (it can actually go higher than this)
- Resolution, color stream: 640 x 480 (again, it can go higher)

I don't see anything mentioning noise, but I can say it's pretty minimal except along surface edges where it can become more noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

My experience is that it is not that exact. It's pretty OK, but when you compare it to tape measure, then it is not exactly matching. I made an Excel with measurements for every 10mm, and it just doesn't hold up, especially things that are more then 2500mm away, but more closer too.

Keep also in mind that the actual depth pixels is a lot lower then is advertised. The electronics inside fills in the gasps, that's why you see small area artifacts, and not something like pixel data. In essence this means that 320x240 has 1/8 pixels covered by a "real" measurement, other pixels are calculated. So you could use 640x480; but it would only CPU/UBS resource and will not make your application see better.

That's just my two cents of experience, I'm programming robotics.